# Net Primary Production for every July very year error

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I would like to use nested Function for NPP value for every month every year,
but I always get error that I did not have input for select Parameter even though I already write the bands that I am working on.

```
// Create an apply a series of nested functions to retrieve the first NPP image from July of each year
var JulyNPP =  ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(years.map(function (y) {
                return months.map(function(m){
                      var w = collectionMODIS.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(y, y, 'year'))
                              .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(m, m, 'month'))
                              .first()                              
                              .select("Npp")
                          return w.copyProperties(w,['system:time_start']);
                            });
                }).flatten());
 
print(JulyNPP, "July NPP values per year");
```

You can find my code at https://code.earthengine.google.com/c4be4d01f894f531d8837092a11842e2

Answer (score 0):

Your filter doesn't return an image:

```
var test = collectionMODIS.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(2000, 2000, 'year'))
                              .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(7, 7, 'month'))
                              .first()                              
                              // .select("Npp")
print(test, 'test is empty')
```

==================== EDIT =========================

```
 var test = collectionMODIS.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(y, y, 'year'))
                              .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(m, m, 'month'))
                              .size()  
 var conditional = ee.Algorithms.If(test.gte(1), 
                                collectionMODIS.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(y, y, 'year'))
                              .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(m, m, 'month')).first().select('Npp'),
                              ee.Image(0).rename('Npp').set({'system:time_start':ee.Date.fromYMD(y,m,1)}))
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/34a63fd4683d21907c013c85b0921023

So you probably have to make sure that you either know for all timesteps there is an actual image available. Or you need to build in an algorithms.if() statement that ensures empty images are returned. But that would depend on your requirements for further processing.

Comment: How to avoid this empty image, should I return the image? It is fine if there is any empty image for certain time

Comment: I'll adjust the answer but you are trying to filter a MODIS collection that contains 1 observation per year so the july filter (month 7) is always going to return something empty. The approach should work for monthly imge collections